# Removing phrases which repeat in an array of strings in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, nlp, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene to search and index pages, and unfortunately it crawls the page and sucks in a lot of common text, for example the language selector "American, Brazil, etc." show up and dilute my search results.

I would like to calculate common words and phrases, if a lot of the documents contain "How to help" I'd like to eliminate that from the index. This seems like a NLP that has been solved, is there a way I can analyze what is essentially an array of strings and removing phrases that keep showing up?

Answer (score 1):

Create a 'HashSet' of the common words that you want to filter out. Then, copy your array into a new array one item at a time checking for membership in the hashset before copying. Hashsets are the fastest searchable structure in the .NET framework. It only checks for membership.

```
private HashSet<string> commonWords = new HashSet<string>() { 
    "How to help", "Click Here", "Home", "Facebook", "Like Me", "Buy Viagra"
};

List<string> newList = new List<string>();

foreach(string s in luceneArray)
    if(!commonWords.Contains(s))
        newList.Add(s);
```

At least it's a starting point. If your original list is massive, use a dictionary or make a binary tree.

Comment: Great idea.  Personally I would go with a dictionary but a hash set would work great if the data set is small to medium size.

Answer (score 0):

Well Not Sure if I actually understand it correctly, maybe more complicated than I think.
but if it is a List of strings that contain your items, you can use

```
MyList.Distinct();
```

to do that.

Comment: If he's got them in a list, that would remove duplicates.  But he's asking to *REMOVE* the recurring phrases, which would have them occur *zero* times, not *one* time.